# Delay on condition

Tags: .net, system.reactive, reactivex

There is a code:

```cs
someObservable.Select(x => getY(x));    
Y getY(X x)
{
  if (x.Value == X.ABC)
    return new Y(1);
  else
    return new Y(2);
}
```

On some condition I need to double check x.Value after some period of time.
The simplest and bad solution is to use Thread.Sleep:

```cs
Y getY(X x)
{
  if (x.Value == X.ABC)
    return new Y(1);
  else
  if (x.SomethingElse == true)
  {
     Thread.Sleep(timeout);
     if (x.Value == X.ABC)
       return new Y(1);
     else
       return new Y(2);
  }
}
```

What is the correct code here?
I need events to be ordered the same way I receive.
It means if I have a delay and I get a new value it has to wait to be processed.

Answer (score 2):

The solution (from https://rsdn.org/forum/dotnet/6629370.1) is to return IObservable rather than Y in getY and make Observable.Delay with Concat.

```
IObservable<Y> getY(X x)
{
  if (x.Value == X.ABC)
    return Observable.Return(new Y(1));
  else
  if (x.SomethingElse == true)
  {
     return Observable.Delay(Observable.Return(x), timeout).Select(xx => xx.Value == X.ABC ? new Y(1) : new Y(2));
  }
}
```

or

```
IObservable<Y> getY(X x)
{
  return Observable.Create<Y>(async (obs, token) =>
  {
    if (x.Value == X.ABC)
        obs.OnNext(new Y(1));
    else
    if (x.SomethingElse == true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(timeout, token);
        if (x.Value == X.ABC)
           obs.OnNext(new Y(1));
        else
           obs.OnNext(new Y(2));
     }
   }
 }
```

And then: someObservable.Select(x => getY(x)).Concat();

Comment: This will work. I was thinking of using a `SelectMany`, which is equivalent to `Select` followed by a `Merge`, which wouldn't preserve order. This solution, however, will correctly preserve order.

Comment: You do end up creating new a observable for every value though.

Comment: Yes, it also allowed me to make short delays instead of one long in Rx way:
Observable.Timer(0, 100ms).Take(tries).Select(x => ..).Where(x != null).Take(1);

Answer (score 1):

If this is a general problem, I suggest you implement a custom operator.
The delay method has an overload which accepts another observable to control the delay timing. In the example, even numbers push immediately while odd numbers are delayed;

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
          .Delay(i => (i % 2 == 0) ? Observable.Return(0L) : Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.9)))
          .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

EDIT:
Here is a simpler, order preserving operator for delay:

```
  static IObservable<T> DelayOrdered<T>(this IObservable<T> observable, Func<T, TimeSpan> delaySelector, IScheduler scheduler = default(IScheduler))
        {
            scheduler = scheduler ?? DefaultScheduler.Instance;
            return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
            {
                var now = scheduler.Now;

                return observable
                       .Subscribe(value =>
                {
                    now = now.Add(delaySelector(value));
                    scheduler.Schedule(now, () => observer.OnNext(value));
                });
            });
        }
```

Usage:

```
  Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2))
                      .DelayOrdered(i => (i % 2 == 0) ? TimeSpan.Zero : TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                      .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

Order will be preserved because the absolute scheduled time can only increase.

Comment: Thanks. The only issue that I need to preserve order. I got some proposal for solution below. What you think about it ?

Comment: @NN_ yes, your proposed solution should preserve order. I think you could make it more efficient though.